# How to port older (not event driven) software to javascript

Tags: javascript, porting

I want to port some old software to javascript. These programs are typically not event driven and just turn in a loop. They only pause to get input from the input stream. I can't just convert them to javascript since there is no equivalent for a classic pascal or c read instruction. I thought it would be possible to use an input field which would fire an onchange event. My program would then be suspended until the event fires. But apparently you can't suspend a JS program.

My second attempt was to set a flag on the onchange event. My program stays in a loop until the flag is set and then reads the value of the input field. But to prevent the browser from getting blocked by this loop I need some sleep functionality between two polls. Apparently there is no equivalent of a sleep function in JS.

How can this be done ?

Comment: JS *already has* an event loop. You don't need to set up another one on top of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use Promises and `await`/`async` to create code that looks like what you know from blocking code.

But it is important to note that this is **not** blocking code. At the `await` other code waiting to be executed can interleave.

```js
function waitForIntput(id) {
  // create a Promise that resolves at the input event
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let elm = document.getElementById(id)

    function listener(evt) {
       // remove the listener so that no memory leaking occures
       elm.removeEventListener('input', listener)

       // resolve the promise with the current value of the element
       resolve(elm.value)
    }

    // call the listener on the input event
    elm.addEventListener('input', listener, false);
  })

}

(async function() {
  while(true) {
     console.log('before waitForIntput')
     console.log(await waitForIntput('test'))
     console.log('after waitForIntput')
  }
}())
```

```html
<input id="test">
```

If it is a good idea to solve it that way depends on the exact use-case. In general you should check how the task you want to perform should be solved in the new environment, instead of forcing the old style into the new environment.

Answer (score 1):

If you're coming from a language that does something like...

```
while(true) {
  x = readInput();
  processInput(x);
}
```

Then you're correct, there is no direct equivalent in JavaScript. You need to forget about looping, and instead think of everything that happens in your loop *before* it blocks on user input as one part that sets up an event, and everything that happens *after* as a *callback* that handles that event.

The above (very trivial) program would be rewritten in JavaScript as something like:

```
readInput().then((x) => { processInput(x) });
```